# Which airlines (if any) offer vertical seating seats on their journeys from the UK?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, seating

Long time ago I remember reading about them on RyanAir but I can't find anything on their website?

[image]

Comment: From the UK to where? The world?

Comment: You *want* to find these?

Comment: @thanby yes.. obviously

Comment: @MarkMayo to anywhere

Comment: There is no reason for airlines to do this because they are limited by weight not space.

Comment: @JamesRyan If they're not limited by space, then how come I often feel crammed into my seat?

Comment: @domen so that they can space first class out and charge more.

Comment: @JamesRyan For larger aircraft, passenger cabins are generally limited by floor space (and how quickly they can evacuate the passengers,) not by weight. See [this question on Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52669/12011) and [this question on Aviation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17441/755) for more details. However, passenger weight does matter more for smaller aircraft (and it matters a lot for very small aircraft.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So three years ago, [RyanAir sort of implied they might do standing seats](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-2229734/Michael-OLeary-calls-standing-room-space-Ryanair-flights.html#ixzz36xNVyJfN) if allowed.  The world looked on in horror, shock, half contemplated if they'd do it for one hour flights, and then it went away.

Except it didn't.  Airlines have half-mentioned it since then, including [both RyanAir and SpringAir](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/07/10/travel/standing-cabin-plane-study/).

Again, this is just talk at this stage, until it wasn't, when AirBus filed their [saddleseat](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/07/17/travel/airbus-saddle-seat-patent/) patent, which was almost standing seats. You perch on the seats instead of reclining.  [Here's the official patent](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=2014159444A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20140612&DB=EPODOC&locale=en_EP).

A study in Malaysia then showed that [on a 737-300, a standing cabin would lead to a 21% increase in capacity and drop tickets up to 44%](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/07/10/travel/standing-cabin-plane-study/).

And then this year, not to be outdone, Boeing filed a patent for an [upright sleep support system](http://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-advice/boeing-issued-a-patent-for-an-upright-sleep-support-system/story-fn6yjmoc-1227295633891) on planes, which could in theory reduce the need to recline seats, and some argue could be combined with other formats to allow standing too.  The more the merrier, perhaps?

While no airline has actually offered this *yet*, given the experiments in seating (see AirNZ's cuddle class) and the ever increasing demand to fit more people on flights for less money, many people (including that aforementioned study) predict standing class might not be that far away.

Comment: Oh, I'd like to test that "upright sleep support system"; I just can't manage to sleep in not-so reclining seats.

Answer (score 27):

This was a publicity stunt by Ryanair. No such product exists and it is dubious it would be approved as safe by the Civil Aviation Authority.

It's worth noting that Ryanair and Easyjet are already close to the maximum number of people they can allow on board based on the size of the emergency exits on the aircraft they use. Therefore this product would not really offer them any advantage in terms of densification.

Comment: Technically such products do exist, in patent form at least...

Comment: @MarkMayo I think we will have to disagree on the meaning of "exist" here. A patent is little more than a feasible idea. Most companies with the resources will patent everything they can, even if they have no intention to produce it.

Comment: that's why I specified patent, I'm not calling you wrong, I'm just saying it wasn't *merely* a publicity stunt - they're not alone in spending time and resources around this topic.  Here's hoping no airline actually implements it.

Comment: I have little doubt that Ryanair would do this if they thought they could get away with it.

Comment: @MarkMayo You said the *product* exists. It doesn't. The idea for the product exists but that idea has not been turned into a product.

Comment: Yeah, I also said "Technically" and "in patent form".  Context.  But it's not really worth it - I'm not disagreeing with you.